# How to I identify the diene and dienophile through retrosynthesis of a given compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I'm stuck while finding what to use to make this compound:

[image: Retrosynthesis product]

My first attempt was to use a triple bond as dienophile and a ring as my diene, as shown below -

[image: My attempt at the synthesis]

But I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. For formatting help visit the [help] and for more information about this page, take the [tour].  
Also your product lacks some charges or protons.

Comment: Thats the way it was given to me by a friend but yeah there would be a -2 on the co3 It would be trivial if the bottom double bond was on the bond that connects the two rings but using the diels-alder mechanism I can't really see how to get that structure. Why guess so far is I need a triple bond dieophile and a ring as my diene

Comment: It would be great if you could would your retrosynthesis (the one from your comment) into your question! It would be a waste if the question would get closed **despite** the fact that you have definitely thought on it and came to a reasonable approach!

Comment: The compound as drawn is impossible. You're alluding to carbonate [CO3(2-)] in the comment, but that cannot be attached to the structure. Draw it out completely to convince yourself. One mistake in a structure makes me skeptical about the accuracy of the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\ce{CO3}$ substituents are questionable. Let's assume that this is $\ce{CO2Me}$ instead!

Since this is homework, I won't provide a full solution but:

1. Note that double bond patterns may isomerize (in the direction of conjugation).
2. Alkynes can serve as dienophiles too!

[image]

Comment: ![Diels-Alder product](http://imgur.com/W87fwow)   This was my first attempt is this on the right track? Not quite right yet.

Comment: @Loststudent22 Diels-Alder reaction looks fine to me. Remember #1 in my answer. What about adding a strong, bulky base and subsequent quenching?

Comment: I kind of see what your saying, so the reaction couldn't be done in one concerted mechanism?

Comment: @Loststudent22 I just don't see that, but maybe I'm missing something and I'm preoccupied with the same retrosynthesis that you had in mind too.